How does the convergence of the free energy for the cutoff measure, imply the convergence of the cutoff measure?
In Barashkov and Gubinelli (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10814), the authors define the cutoff measure $\nu_T$ for $T>0$, as:
\begin{equation}
\nu_T(d\phi)=\frac{\exp\left[-V_T(\phi_T)\right]}{\mathfrak{L}_T}\vartheta(d\phi) \\
V_T(\varphi):=\lambda\int_{\Lambda}\left(|\varphi(\xi)|^4-a_T|\varphi(\xi)|^2-b_T\right)d\xi,\,\,\mathcal{L}_T:=\int e^{-V_T(\phi_T)}\vartheta(d\phi)
\end{equation}
with $\lambda\geq 0$, $\vartheta$ is a centred Gaussian measure with covariance $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$, $a_T$, $b_T$ given constants and $\phi=\rho_T\ast\phi$ for some appropriate cutoff such that $\rho_T\rightarrow \delta$. The aim is to construct the $\Phi^4_d$ Gibbs measure by studying the convergence of $\nu_T$.
To this end, the following normalised free energy $\mathcal{W}_T$ for the cutoff measure is defined:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{W}_T(f):=-\frac{1}{|\Lambda|}\log\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\Lambda)}\exp\left[-|\Lambda|f(\phi)-V_T(\phi)\right]\vartheta(d\phi),
\end{equation}
for $f\in C(\mathcal{S}'(\Lambda),\mathbb{R})$ and $\Lambda=(\mathbb{R}/ 2\pi L\mathbb{Z})$. The main result in the paper (Theorem 1) says that in $d=3$ and for a choice of $a_T,b_T$ $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{W}_T(f)$ exists for $f$ with linear growth.
My query is regarding this remark they make: "Theorem 1 implies directly the convergence of $(\nu_T)_T$ to a limit measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{S}'(\Lambda)$. Taking $f$ in the linear dual of $\mathcal{C}^{−1/2−\kappa}$ it also gives the following formula for the Laplace transform of $\nu$:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\Lambda)}\exp(-f(\phi))\nu(d\phi)=\exp[-|\Lambda|(\mathcal{W}(f/|\Lambda|)-\mathcal{W}(0))].
\end{equation} Why is this true?
